# Prove $m_nx+b_n$ is integrable on given interval.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f(x)=m_nx+b_n$ on $[n-1,n)$ for $n=1,2,3,...k$, then $f$ is integrable on $[0,k-\frac{1}{2}]$

Okay I have already established previously that mx+b is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

And I know that if a function is continuous on some closed interval $[a,b]$ , then the fuction is integrable on $[a,b]$.

But how do I prove specifically with what I have been given in my question; that is, this is true when the function is defined on $[n-1,n)$ for $n=1,2,...k$ and is thus integrable on the interval $[0,k-\frac{1}{2}]$

I would greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^{k-1/2} f(x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x)dx +\int_1^2 f(x)dx...\int_{k-1}^{k-1/2} f(x)dx$

If you have shown that f(x) is integrable over each of the piece, then it is integrable over the entire interval.

Comment: So would a proof by induction work well for this?